# How to get Call history in c# with windows mobile 6.1 sdk

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sdk

It's there a place i can find documentation on the windows mobile 6.1 sdk. I need to get the call log history in my application.

Nobody know how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the Phone API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416387.aspx

Specifically, there are calls to "PhoneOpenCallLog", "PhoneSeekCallLog," etc.